# rsyncing between two non-login users

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have two machines `A` and `B`, both of which have 3 users:

- `root` (I don't know a password can just switch using `sudo su -`)
- `login` (used for `ssh`ing into both machines, has a password, is a sudoer)
- `mysql` (standard non-interactive user running mysql server)

What I need to do is to rsync data directory (`dir`) belonging to `mysql` from machine `A` to machine `B`.

Obviously I can't just do:

```
rsync -avpE /dir/ B:/dir/
```

Because neither A nor B have read access to `dir`

I can't do:

```
sudo -u mysql rsync -avpE /dir/ B:/dir/
```

Because now A has access to `dir` but B doesn't.

So is it possible to construct an rsync command so I copy data across without using some temporary space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` has an option called `--rsync-path` that might help you:

```
$ rsync |& grep rsync-path
     --rsync-path=PROGRAM    specify the rsync to run on the remote machine
```

The idea is to ask (the local) `rsync` to ssh to the remote machine (as user `login`) and then when it wants to call `rsync` on the remote machine, have it call `sudo -u mysql rsync` instead of plain `rsync`. So something like that:

```
sudo -u mysql rsync -avpE --rsync-path="sudo -u mysql rsync" /dir/ login@B:/dir/
```

Of course for this to work, the user `login` on the remote machine must be able to `sudo -u mysql` without a password.

Comment: Hi redneb, this works, would it be possible to achieve if the login user has to specify a password? I was trying something like sudo -u mysql rsync -avpE --rsync-path="echo pass | sudo -Su mysql rsync" /dir/ login@B:/dir/ but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think `sudo` can read its password from its `stdin`, for security reasons.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, `sudo` has the `-S` flag for that, i.e. `echo 'password' | sudo -S command`. I don't know if this would work in your case though, because `rsync` on the remote side will use the `stdin` too.

Comment: As you see my example in comment already includes the `S` flag and I tried to execute this. It fails with an error, I can paste it later.

Comment: Oops, my bad I didn't notice it. So apparently passing the password that way messes with `rsync`'s use of `stdin`.